# R: How to use dist.circular?

Tags: r, distance, geodesic-sphere

I want to mesurare the distance among vectors with torsional angles.

To do it, i was suggested to use the geodesic distance implemented in R software.

I have installed R as well as their main dependence such as circular.

But, when I am using it, [such as](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/circular/versions/0.4-93/topics/dist.circular):

```
dist.circular(carbo2, method = "geodesic", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE)
```

I am getting:

```
Error: could not find function "dist.circular"
```

and I don't know why